# Sequence kubernates Operators

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-pod, fabric8

I have two k8s operators say operatorA and operatorB . I have both custom resources present in microservice(helm/templates).

how can I make sure custom resource for operatorB applied only after operatorA custom resource is applied?

Comment: They operate on different CRDs

Comment: yes but one operator output is input for other operator custom resource

Comment: They react on desired state, and act when the desired state changes.

Answer (score 1):

there is no validation between the two CRDs, only your operator can affect by the installation order, therefore, all you need to do is to make sure that the CRDs will install before the operator itself.

you can achieve this by using a `crds` folder, you can read about this in the official [docs](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts_hooks/#hooks-and-the-release-lifecycle)

Comment: I have crds deployed . the question is ordering of custom resources deployment from operator

Comment: Alternatively, you could use the wait command to wait for a specific condition to be met before applying the custom resource for operatorB.